# Number symbol in img tag make page reload 3 times?

Tags: jquery, refresh, image

This might be a really simple answer but I just spent the last hour trying to figure out why my php page was refreshing three times after the initial load.

```
<img src="#" style="what:ever;" alt="" />
```

The culprit turned out to be a  number symbol in the source attribute. Everything works as expected after I changed the code to:

```
<img src="" style="what:ever;" alt="" />
```

This image tag does get modified by jquery if that is relavant I do not know.

So why did I just waste the last hour of my life?

Comment: `src="#"` is basically shorthand for "the current url". Which is invalid for an image, since you'd be trying to load a chunk of html as an image.

Answer (score 0):

"src="#" is basically shorthand for "the current url". Which is invalid for an image, since you'd be trying to load a chunk of html as an image."

– Marc B

Answer (score 0):

What Marc B said it correct.

Additional information : 
    The browser has a behavior that whenever it look a "**src**" attribute, it will try to **load the value of the src attribute**.

I can point "**script**" tag for this. When you specify **src** attribute with some URL, it will try to load that result into your script tag. Similarly, **img** tag will also try to load the image from the path mentioned in the src attribute.

Now in this case, when it looks a "**#**", it will try to load "**#**" which actually means the current page in our context. Thats the reason.